# Laravel join with multiple condition

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have this line of code:

```
$user['preference'] = PdTpreference::join('pd_tprofessional_preference', 'pd_tprofessional_preference.fkpreference', '=', 'pd_tpreference.pkpreference AND pd_tprofessional_preference.fkprofessional =' . $tmp->pkprofessional, 'left')->get();
```

But it comes out like this:

```
select * from `pd_tpreference` left join `pd_tprofessional_preference` on `pd_tprofessional_preference`.`fkpreference` = `pd_tpreference`.`pkpreference AND pd_tprofessional_preference`.`fkprofessional =12` where `pd_tpreference`.`deleted_at` is null
```

When I am expecting it come out like so:

```
select * from `pd_tpreference` left join `pd_tprofessional_preference` on `pd_tprofessional_preference`.`fkpreference` = `pd_tpreference`.`pkpreference` AND `pd_tprofessional_preference`.`fkprofessional` = 12 where `pd_tpreference`.`deleted_at` is null
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem with the following:

```
$user['preference'] = PdTpreference::leftJoin('pd_tprofessional_preference', function($q) use ($tmp){ $q->on('pd_tprofessional_preference.fkpreference', '=', 'pd_tpreference.pkpreference')->where('pd_tprofessional_preference.fkprofessional', '=', $tmp->pkprofessional); })->get();
```